# Method not recognizing the call this in JavaFX application

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, nodes

I'm working on a program that displays circles colliding with the wall and with themselves.

I'm having trouble with the method that will compensate for collisions.

```
public class bouncyFX extends Application {
    public ArrayList<Ball> arr = new ArrayList<Ball>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    static Pane pane;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        pane = new Pane();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        pane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(final MouseEvent event) {
                final Ball ball = new Ball(event.getX(), event.getY(), 40, Color.AQUA);
                ball.circle.relocate(event.getX(), event.getY());
                pane.getChildren().addAll(ball.circle);
                arr.add(ball);
                final Bounds bounds = pane.getBoundsInLocal();
                final Timeline loop = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    double deltaX = ball.ballDeltaX;
                    double deltaY = ball.ballDeltaY;
                    public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
                        ball.circle.setLayoutX(ball.circle.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
                        ball.circle.setLayoutY(ball.circle.getLayoutY() + deltaY);

                        final boolean atRightBorder = ball.circle.getLayoutX() >= (bounds.getMaxX()-ball.circle.getRadius());
                        final boolean atLeftBorder = ball.circle.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX()+ball.circle.getRadius());
                        final boolean atBottomBorder = ball.circle.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMaxY()-ball.circle.getRadius());
                        final boolean atTopBorder = ball.circle.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY()+ball.circle.getRadius());
                        if(atRightBorder || atLeftBorder)
                            deltaX *= -1;
                        if(atBottomBorder || atTopBorder)
                            deltaY *= -1;
                        for(int i = 0; i<arr.size(); i++){
                            for(int j = i+1; j<arr.size()-1; j++){
                               arr.get(i).collisionMagnitued(arr.get(j));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }));
                loop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
                loop.play();
            }
        });
    }
    class Ball{
        public Circle circle;
        public double ballDeltaX = 3;
        public double ballDeltaY = 3;

        public void AddBall(Ball b){
            arr.add(b);
        }

        public Ball(double X, double Y, double Rad, Color color) {
            circle = new Circle(X, Y, Rad);
            circle.setFill(color);
        }

        private boolean defineCollision(Ball b){
            double xd = this.circle.getLayoutX() - b.circle.getLayoutX();
            double yd = this.circle.getLayoutY() - b.circle.getLayoutY();
            double sumRad = this.circle.getRadius() + b.circle.getRadius();
            double squareRad = Math.pow(sumRad, 2);

            double distSquare = Math.pow(xd, 2) + Math.pow(yd, 2);
            if(distSquare <= squareRad){
                return true;
            }return false;
        }
        public void collisionMagnitued(Ball b){
            if(this.defineCollision(b)){
                double tempDeltaX = ballDeltaX;
                double tempDeltaY = ballDeltaY;

                if((this.ballDeltaX < 0 && b.ballDeltaX > 0) || (this.ballDeltaX >0 && b.ballDeltaX <0)){
                    this.ballDeltaX *= -this.ballDeltaX;
                    b.ballDeltaX *= -b.ballDeltaX;
                    System.out.println("tredje");
                }
                if((this.ballDeltaY < 0 && b.ballDeltaY > 0) || (this.ballDeltaY > 0 && b.ballDeltaY < 0)){
                    this.ballDeltaY *= -this.ballDeltaY;
                    b.ballDeltaY *= -b.ballDeltaY;
                    System.out.println("fjärde");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Knull");
                    this.ballDeltaX *= -1;
                    b.ballDeltaX *= -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Balls (or circles) are created and are bouncing against the Bounds as expected.

The Collision detection method works as I'm getting print statements inside the last method. However, it seems that there's something wrong with either my ArrayList not being filled with objects or the method trying to compare the parameter Ball and the Ball that calls the method.

Am I way off? Not sure how I'm suppossed to go forth from here.

Comment: Just a general SO comment here: you have 15 questions, almost all are answered, but you haven't marked a single answer as "correct". You're more likely to get questions answered if you give positive feedback to those who answer. (Or, if none of the answers are what you are looking for, you should clarify the questions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues with your logic:

The first problem is that when the balls "bounce" off the boundaries of the pane, you don't change their `ballDeltaX` or `ballDeltaY` values (you just change a local value in the animation loop and use the local value to update the position). So the first time two balls collide, both of their `ballDeltaX` and `ballDeltaY` values are equal to +3 (the initial value), which may not represent the actual direction the animation loop is moving them in. In fact, you never actually use any updated values of `ballDeltaX` or `ballDeltaY` to compute the new positions; you get the initial values of those variables, copy them into `deltaX` and `deltaY`, and then just compute the new positions using `deltaX` and `deltaY`. So if you change `ballDeltaX` and `ballDeltaY`, the animation loop never sees the change.

The `for` loops look wrong to me; I don't think they compare the last two elements of the list. (When `i = arr.size()-2` in the penultimate iteration of the outer loop, your inner loop is `for (int j = arr.size() - 1; j < arr.size() -1; j++) {...}` which of course never iterates.) I think you want the bounding conditions to be `i < arr.size() - 1` and `j < arr.size()`, i.e. the other way around.

And then your `if`/`else` structure in `collisionMagnitued(...)` is probably not exactly what you want. I'm not sure what you're trying to implement there, but the `else` clause only kicks in if the second `if` is `false`, and no matter what happens in the first `if`.

Finally, you are starting a new animation on each mouse click. So, for example, if you have three balls bouncing around, you have three animation loops running, each of which is updating values when the balls collide. You need to start just one loop; it shouldn't do any harm if it refers to an empty list.

Comment: Hi! Adjusted the for-loop to what you suggested. What I'm trying to do in the last method is to compare the first element in the arraylist with all of the others at place 1,2,3 and so on. And the do the same for the rest of the elements. This way I was hoping to be able to check through all possible collisions at every iterations in the TimeLine loop. The statements themselves should compare the current X and Y trajectory of the first element in the outer for-loop, and the following ones in the second for-loop, hope that makes sense!

Comment: I understand what you are doing with the double nested for loop. I don't understand the logic of your if statements.

Comment: I'm under the impression that "this" calls the instance that calls the method, such as ball.collisioMagnitude. 

And the other Ball object goes into the in parameter. I'm trying to see what trajectory the balls have in X and Y directions. And adjust deltaX and deltaY depending on how they hit eachother

Comment: As an example: the first if-statement suggests that if the balls are colliding in opposite directions X-wise. Then they both get negative X-values and repel eachother.

Comment: You have: if the balls are going in the opposite horizontal direction, replace their horizontal velocities with the negative of the square of their current velocity (`dx = dx * (-dx)`). If the balls are going in the opposite vertical direction, replace the vertical velocities with the negative of the square of their vertical velocities, otherwise replace the horizontal velocities with their negatives. I don't understand that logic.

Comment: That doesn't really matter since the method is not recognizing the as seperate balls anyway. It should not be uncommon for to balls to interfere with eachother with one head in the negative x-span and the other in the positive so it should notice this.

Comment: It is certainly recognizing the separate balls (just put `if (this == b) throw new Error("Self check");` at the beginning of the method); but your animation loop doesn't actually use the balls' `ballDeltaX` and `ballDeltaY` variables in running the animation, and bouncing off the walls doesn't change those values. See update.